# I want to append first line but it append last line of multiple data

Tags: java, io, text-files

```
public class AddMoney {

    RegisterAndLogin rl = new RegisterAndLogin();
    private String UserName;
    File file;
    int balance;
    String sourceamt;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String path = "D:\\PesonalAccoutant\\account\\";
    String readData;
    FileWriter fw;
    BufferedWriter bw;
    StringBuilder sb;
    BufferedReader br;

    public AddMoney(String UserName) {
        this.UserName = UserName;
    }

    public void acceptmoneyvalus() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("<1> add money to account");
        System.out.println("<2> remove money from account");
        addmoneytoaccount();

    }

    public void addmoneytoaccount() throws IOException {
        try {
            file = new File(path + UserName + ".txt");
            fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            file.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("file create");

            if (file.exists()) {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                if (file.length() == 0) {
                    System.out.println("reading null data");
                    bw.write("Balance=" + 0);
                    bw.newLine();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the amount.");
                    balance = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please enter source of the ammount");
                    sourceamt = scanner.next();
                    addBalance(balance);
                    bw.append("Amount=");
                    bw.append("" + balance);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.append("Source of the amount=" + sourceamt);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.newLine();

                } else {
                    System.out.println("else blco");
                    System.out.println("Please enter the amount.");
                    balance = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Please enter source of the ammount");
                    sourceamt = scanner.next();
                    addBalance(balance);
                    bw.append("Amount=");
                    bw.append("" + balance);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.append("Source of the amount=" + sourceamt);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.newLine();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("try to register again...");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error" + e);
        } finally {
            bw.close();

        }
    }

    private void addBalance(int balance) throws IOException {
        try {
            int count = 0;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while ((readData = br.readLine()) != null) {
                count++;
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                if (count == 1) {

                    sb.append(readData);
                    sb.delete(0, 8);
                    System.out.println("full datd is"+readData);
                    //  int i=(Integer)sb;
                    int i = Integer.valueOf(sb.toString());
                    int totalbalance = balance + i;
                    System.out.println("balance is " + sb.toString());
                    System.out.println("total balnce" + totalbalance);
                    bw.append("Balance=" + totalbalance);
                    bw.newLine();
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Error " + e);
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }

    }

}
```

I wanted to add balance in first line but when I add more data it append last two line instead of beginning of the file.
I want every time I add money It must reflect in balance with addition of entered amount

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((readData = br.readLine()) != null) {
            count++;
            sb = new StringBuilder();
```

inside the `while loop` in `addbalance()` method you are `instantiating` a new `StringBuilder` each time.

if you wanto `append` data to the `StringBuilder sb`; you can declare this as 
a instance variable or declare the variable outside the whileLoop like this

```
sb = new StringBuilder(); 
while ((readData = br.readLine()) != null) {
                ++count;
```

and make sure to change `count++` to `++count`.
since you just need to read the first line you dont have to go with a `while loop` you can just use `readLine();` method

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
private void addBalance(int balance) throws IOException{
    readData = br.readLine(); //first line 
    sb.append(readData);
}
```

Comment: I made changes as said but that aint working.still appends at last record.

Comment: Balance=0
Amount=100
Source of the amount=dad

Balance=100
Amount=100
Source of the amount=dad
text file data.
Balance=100
Amount=100
Source of the amount=dad